# How to add version parameter to JS & CSS files to avoid browser cache?

Tags: 7, javascript, caching

What is the best way to append the file version number in order to give to the users the right JS/CSS files?

Actually i am working on a website which has a browser cache expiration date set to 5 days.

Comment: Drupal 7 & 8 both do that automatically for every asset added through the API (drupal_add_js/drupal_add_css/#attached). If it's missing in your installation, it'll need some digging to find out what code is responsible for removing it. If you're not adding assets through the API, that'll be thing to change. Of course bear in mind that you need to think about this in terms of full page cache too. The cache buster will change automatically, when it needs to or the css/js cache is flushed, but unless the relevant page cache is cleared, users will never know because they'll be served the old HTML

Comment: I can't vote to close questions yet, but I'd do so here, as this question is far too broad. If you find you need to disable caching for attached resources for certain reasons, please describe your use case in more detail, how you add these resources, why/for whom they shall not be cached, and why you find you have to add cache busters manually.

Comment: correct, add this as answer

Comment: @Mike Why do you want to work around what Drupal already provides via it's API? I set the browser cache to 1 year but changes to the CSS and JS files go out when I flush the cache.

Comment: @mikeytown2 it was something done by someone else in an anti-pattern way

Comment: You should be able to add the js via drupal_add_ja right? If not can you please explain why?

Comment: i found some css were added without using drupal_add_css

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add the 'css_js_query_string' variable to the end of your css/js path. This will have to be hard-coded or via a preprocess function in template.php.

Example:

```
<script src="/path/to/js/file/file.js?ver=<?php print variable_get('css_js_query_string', ''); ?>"></script>
```